# How to call one model in the other in Keras？

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My model structure showed below.

I have built the `model_1` and get the `loss_1`. Further more, I tried to add the predicting process of `pretrained_model` in function `get_loss()` where I can get `out_1`. And I want to make the sum of `loss_1` and `loss_2` as the loss of `model_1` directly.

Because of the static graph mechanism of tensorflow, as the backend of keras, it seems that my code is wrong.

How should I do it?

```
def get_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss_1 = fun(y_true, y_pred)       # this line is OK
    loss_2 = pretrained_model(y_pred)  # wrong!!!
    return loss_1+loss_2

model_1.compile(optimizer, loss = get_loss)
model_1.fit_generator(...)



        input
          |
       model_1
          |
 label  out_1
  |_______|___________________
      |                       |
    loss_1     pretrained_model(only predict)
      |                       |
      |           loss_2(predict result)
      |_______________________|
                 |
     plus together as mode_1's loss
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to build your keras model with 2 outputs.
If you compile a model with multiple outputs the compile function will take as loss parameter a list of loss function which should be the same length as the list of your outputs to init the model class(2 in your case).

During training the loss functions 'will be summed automatically'. This means that the weight updates for model_1 from the gradients resulting from loss_1 and the weight updates from the gradients from loss_2 will be added together. If you want to add the losses with a weight you can use the parameter loss_weights in model.compile.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I still get two questions. 1. the pretrained_model is only for predict, so I have to call `pretrained_mode.predict_on_batch(x)` and `x`  should be a numpy array according to keras's document. However, what I got from `out_1` is a tensor. How should I deal with it? 2. How to freeze the weights of `pretrained_model` to prevent from being trained?

Comment: You have to include the layers from pretrained model inside your model. So using an already compiled model inside another model isn't possible. You have to implement this on the layer basis. The answer is like you thought in freezing the layers of the pretrained model. https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-keras-layers